# window.location.pathname vs. $location.$$path in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm evaluating the path for some logic in my routes and controllers, and it seems like `window.location.pathname` works just fine as an alternative to injecting `$location` for `$location.$$path`, but I'm not sure if Angular has issues when using window.location that I'm not aware of.

Any problems with using `window.location.pathname'?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can read everything about [`$location` here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

`$location` is an Angular service based on `window.location` but it has more features and properties to be used.

> When should I use $location?
>
> Any time your application needs to react
>   to a change in the current URL or if you want to change the current
>   URL in the browser.

So if you are only getting the location you can safely use `window.location.pathname` cause it's native Javascript but every time you need to interact with the location I would recommend to use `$location` service

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that using `window.location` in a controller does not properly update when `ui-sref` links are used to transition between states.

If I use `$location.path()` instead, the url path is properly updated in the controller, so **$location is clearly the way to go when using Angular / ui-router.**

This is the type of difference I was really looking for when asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Angular.js is a *framework* in JS so, that would work perfectly, but my recommendation to you would be, as a matter of principle, if you pick a framework, work within the framework. And use $location, and checkout the $route.

I hope it helps.